# How are biological oxygen demand and depth related?

Tags: hydrology, water, groundwater

What is the relation between [biological oxygen demand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biochemical_oxygen_demand) (BOD) and depth? I need to calculate the BOD of a drinking water tank and I have ultimate BOD at the surface of water, but I need to calculate it when depth varies. My calculations need an equation of de-oxygenation constant rate and BOD.

Comment: What is [BOD] ?

Comment: Biological oxygen demand

Comment: assuming BOD is proportional to SOD ,t here might be some relation with sediment composition with could be related with depth . Further read : http://ascelibrary.org/doi/abs/10.1061/(ASCE)0733-9372(1994)120:5(996)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you referring to the relationship between pressure and biological oxygen deficiency? Can you rephrase the question please?

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on location? Can you be more specific and clearer in what you are asking?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by calculate the BOD of a water tank. What depth, in the tank? That question is taggedgroundwater but I don't think you mean groundwater. What is your application? Are you sure you ask about earth science and not environemtnal engineering?

Answer (score 2):

[Biological Oxygen demand](http://www.envexp.com/labmatters/236-understanding-biochemical-oxygen-demand-bod) increases with accumulation of decaying organic matter in a water system. This means that BOD is highest where there is high concentration of decomposing organic matter in that system.

> What is the relation between biological oxygen demand (BOD) and depth?

The answer may vary as in some cases organic matter floats on upper columns of water and can be decomposed readily by aerobic microorganisms manifesting an increased BOD.

However, [this study](http://www.ajol.info/index.php/njt/article/viewFile/123371/112914&ved=0ahUKEwj7pZnU8YnRAhWGOFAKHTMFA4IQFggpMAE&usg=AFQjCNEnuF2BjcS55dH4W9v-T5XSPnFtyA&sig2=PGV0zknU20V_L1XvONSM5g)   which was conducted using waste water from stabilization ponds (depths ranging from 0-5m) shows that there is an increase in the Biological Oxygen Demand with increasing depth and this can be attributed to the settling down of organic matter in these ponds.